Is ${\omega}$ about IAOR same as the ${\omega}$ about axis?
Question -
Imagine a body pure rolling on a flat horizontal ground with an angular velocity ${\omega}$ and the velocity of its center of mass ${v_o}$. What is the velocity and acceleration of the top point of the wheel?
Answer-
Now obviously, the velocity is just ${2v_o}$. But the problem came up for the acceleration part. I simply thought it was ${\omega^2 r}$ [centripital acceleration] but a classmate thought is could be ${\omega^2  .2r}$...
The logic behind his answer was that he liked to look at pure rolling as rotation about the instantaneous axis of rotation (IAOR) and negate the translational parts of the mechanics.
And so, the centripetal acceleration too would be with respect to a radius that was twice as large. I originally thought that since the two rotations were different, the $\omega$ would be different, but that is apparently wrong.
What's the catch? Where are we going wrong?

Consider to spell out acronyms.

Take a camera and chase the centre of mass. This makes the floor move backwards but now the rolling object is doing pure roll. This is a Galilean transformation, and Galilean transformations preserve accelerations. Thus, the centripetal acceleration must be the old value, not your classmate's.
The IAoR trick gets you some stuff correct, but it is not a replacement for actual understanding. The IAoR pivot point is not an inertial frame of reference. So that does not work.
However, it can get the energies correct, by mathematical theorem. Note that the $I$ of IAoR is different from $I_\text{CM}$
